# How to avoid looping of ZipArchieveInputStream to infinity while reading corrupted or invalid zip files?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

`ZipArchieveInputStream` loops to infinity when reading data from stream - when invalid or corrupted zip file is passed over stream.

```
    ZipArchiveInputStream stream = new ZipArchiveInputStream(file, charset, true);

        while((entry = stream.getNextZipEntry())!=null) {
                while((read = stream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                      //This loops to infinity for invalid entry
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the behavior of the Apache Commons class ZipArchiveInputStream that you are using, but maybe you should try switching to the equivalent Java 
[ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) class. I have used it and its getNextEntry method returns null or throws an exception when the entry is corrupted.

Comment: Oh thanks Carlos ! I'm using it to extract the entities present in zip files. Is this achievable with `ZipInputStream` ?

Comment: Yes, looks like it has the same functionality.